# Is there a better why than this nested loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, nested-loops

my problem arises from two DataFrames:DF1 has a number of securities that need prices from our pricing file DF2.

DF1

| Security Number Key | Current Date Price |
| --- | --- |
| A | NaN |
| B | NaN |
| C | NaN |

DF2

| Security_ID | Price |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| B | 200 |
| D | 400 |

My Current code that works, looks like this:

```
for k, v in DF1['Security Number Key'].items():
    for i, n in DF2['Security_ID'].items():
        if v == n:
            DF1['Current Date Price'][k] = DF2['Price'][i]
```

This works but isn't very efficient since my DataFrames are much larger than the examples.

I've also tried using df.query() but when I get a match it returns more than the price.

```
for k, v in DF1['Security Number Key'].items():
        if v in DF2['Security_ID'].values:
                print(DF2.query('Security_ID == @v')['Price'])
```

The result is the output:

```
 0    100
 Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Join the dataframes.

Comment: Use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

Comment: In addition to the comment from @Barmar I would like to refer you to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging You are using the wrong tool for this job. `pd.merge` will solve your problem in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas actually have many functions to avoid looping. One of them is merge. You could work with the resulting dataframe from the following code, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'Security Number Key':['A','B','C'],
               'Current Date Price':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})

DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'Security_ID':['A','B','C'],
               'Price':[100,200,300]})

DF3 = DF1.merge(DF2, left_on='Security Number Key', right_on='Security_ID', how='left')

print(DF3)
```